# Bootstrap 3 mobile version won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some code here in, which when condensed into the mobile version it is improperly rendered:

the html is here(with sidenavbar) 
Does anyone know how to make the boxes render properly in the mobile version

Kind regards,

```css
    .pdsa-summary-block-primary {
        background-color:#428bca;
        color:#fff;
    }
    .pdsa-summary-block-primary .summary-footer {
        background-color:deepskyblue;
    }
    .pdsa-summary-block-primary .summary-footer a {
        color:white;
    }
    .pdsa-summary-block-success {
        background-color:#3c763d;
        color:#fff;
    }
    .pdsa-summary-block-success .summary-footer {
        background-color:green;
    }
    .pdsa-summary-block-success .summary-footer a {
        color:white;
    }
    .pdsa-summary-block-info {
        background-color:#31708f;
        color:#fff;
    }
    .pdsa-summary-block-info .summary-footer {
        background-color:teal;
    }
    .pdsa-summary-block-info .summary-footer a {
        color:white;
    }
    .pdsa-summary-block-danger {
        background-color:#a94442;
        color:#fff;
    }
    .pdsa-summary-block-danger .summary-footer {
        background-color:red;
    }
    .pdsa-summary-block-danger .summary-footer a {
        color:white;
    }
    /*Structure of Summary blocks*/
    .pdsa-summary-block {
        position: relative;
        width:100%;
        margin:0.3em;
        padding:1em;
        min-height:15em;
    }
    .pdsa-summary-block .summary-background i, .pdsa-summary-block .summary-background div {
        margin-left:-0.4em;
        margin-top:0.1em;
        font-size:8em;
        opacity:0.3;
    }
    .pdsa-summary-block .summary-body {
        position:absolute;
        top:1.3em;
        right:0.8em;
    }
    .pdsa-summary-block .summary-body .summary-line-1 {
        text-align:right;
        font-size:xx-large;
    }
    .pdsa-summary-block .summary-body .summary-line-2 {
        text-align:right;
        font-size:medium;
    }
    .pdsa-summary-block .summary-footer {
        position:absolute;
        bottom: 0em;
        right: 0em;
        width:100%;
        padding:0.4em;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size:small;
        opacity:0.6;
    }
    .pdsa-summary-block .summary-footer a {
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .pdsa-summary-block .summary-footer:hover {
        opacity:1;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .pdsa-sn-wrapper {
        position:absolute;
        top:3.6em;
        left:0em;
        width:13em;
        height:100%;
        background-color:#FF9900;
        /*orange.*/
        transition:left 0.3s linear;
        -moz-transition:left 0.3s linear;
        -webkit-transition:left 0.3s linear;
    }
    .pdsa-sn-wrapper ul {
        list-style:none;
        width:11em;
        margin-top:2em;
        margin-left:1em;
        padding:0em;
    }
    .pdsa-sn-wrapper ul li {
        margin-top: 1em;
        margin-bottom:0.5em;
    }
    /* Make hover background .pdsa-sn-wrapper ul li:hover {
                background-color:#760909;
                
            } */
    .pdsa-sn-wrapper ul li a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration:none;
        padding:0.5em;
    }
    .pdsa-sn-wrapper ul li a:hover {
        text-decoration:none;
        color:white;
    }
    .pdsa-sn-wrapper ul li a:active, .pdsa-sn-wrapper ul li a:focus {
        text-decoration:none;
        outline:none;
        color:white;
    }
    .pdsa-sn-wrapper ul .pdsa-sn-brand {
        margin-left:-0.5em;
        font-size: large;
        color:white;
    }
    .pdsa-sn-wrapper ul .pdsa-sn-brand a {
        color:white;
    }
    .pdsa-sn-wrapper ul .pdsa-sn-brand a:hover {
        color:white;
        background:none;
    }
    .pdsa-sn-wrapper ul li a span {
        margin-top:-1em;
        margin-bottom:-1em;
        margin-left:1em;
        margin-top: -1em;
        padding-top:-1em;
        padding-bottom:-1em;
    }
    .pdsa-sn-wrapper ul li ul {
        list-style:none;
        margin-top: 1em;
        margin-left: 1em;
    }
    /*Make left nav turn into icon only on mobile*/
    @media all and (max-width:768px) {
        .pdsa-sn-wrapper {
            left:-10em;
            /*changed above to +13em. now it will take up part of screen.*/
        }
        .pdsa-sn-wrapper ul li:hover {
            background-color:#FF9900;
        }
        .pdsa-sn-wrapper ul li a i {
            padding-left:10em;
            margin-top:-1em;
            margin-bottom:-1em;
        }
        .body-content {
            margin-left:3em;
        }
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="notransition">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <header> <a class="linkStyle" href="Default.html">My Tunes</a>

            </header>
        </div>
        <nav id="sideNavParent" class="pdsa-sn-wrapper">
            <ul>
                <li class="pdsa-sn-brand"><a href="Default.html" class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">Music</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="default.html">
                        <span class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">Home</span>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home visible-xs"></i>
                    </a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ulGenres">
                        <span class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">Genres&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></span>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe visible-xs"></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
                        <ul id="ulGenres" class="collapse" data-parent="#sideNavParent">
                            <li> <a href="Genres.html">All Genres</a>

                            </li>
                            <li> <a href="#">Jazz</a>

                            </li>
                            <li> <a href="#">Country</a>

                            </li>
                            <li> <a href="#">Rock</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ulPlaylists">
                        <span class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">Playlists&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></span>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt visible-xs"></i>
                    </a>

                    <div class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
                        <ul id="ulPlaylists" class="collapse" data-parent="#sideNavParent">
                            <li> <a href="#">All Playlists</a>

                            </li>
                            <li> <a href="#">My Top Rated</a>

                            </li>
                            <li> <a href="#">Top Country</a>

                            </li>
                            <li> <a href="#">Top Classic Rock</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">
                        <span class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">Songs</span>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-music visible-xs"></i>
                    </a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">
                        <span class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">Downloads</span>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download visible-xs"></i>
                    </a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <div class="pdsa-summary-block pdsa-summary-block-primary">
                    <div class="summary-background"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i>

                    </div>
                    <div class="summary-body">
                        <div class="summary-line-1">14</div>
                        <div class="summary-line-2">Genres</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="summary-footer"> <a href="#">View Genres</a>
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="float:right;"></i>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <div class="pdsa-summary-block pdsa-summary-block-success">
                    <div class="summary-background"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i>

                    </div>
                    <div class="summary-body">
                        <div class="summary-line-1">5</div>
                        <div class="summary-line-2">Playlists</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="summary-footer"> <a href="#">See playlists...</a>
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></i>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <div class="pdsa-summary-block pdsa-summary-block-info">
                    <div class="summary-background"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></i>

                    </div>
                    <div class="summary-body">
                        <div class="summary-line-1">2143</div>
                        <div class="summary-line-2">Songs</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="summary-footer"> <a href="#">All Songs.</a>
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></i>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <div class="pdsa-summary-block pdsa-summary-block-danger">
                    <div class="summary-background"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></i>

                    </div>
                    <div class="summary-body">
                        <div class="summary-line-1">1</div>
                        <div class="summary-line-2">Downloads</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="summary-footer"> <a href="#">Get Downloads.</a>
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></i>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                <div class="pdsa-readme-box pdsa-readme-box-primary">
                    <div class="readme-header"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></i>

                    </div>
                    <div class="readme-body">
                         <h1>Free Music</h1>

                        <p>Each day we have a free song selected especially for you!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="readme-footer"> <a href="#">+ See my song</a> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you using CSS media queries? Did you include the correct headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you in adjusting your code or as a base so you have much more control over both.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding-top: 65px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #FF9900;
}
.sidebar-fixed {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 5px 18px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 175px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #FF9900;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
ul.sidebar-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
}
.sidebar-fixed #ulGenres,
.sidebar-fixed #ulPlaylists {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.sidebar-fixed #ulGenres > li,
.sidebar-fixed #ulPlaylists > li {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.sidebar-fixed #ulGenres > li >a,
.sidebar-fixed #ulPlaylists > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.sidebar-list > li {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}
ul.sidebar-list > li > a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar-default .collapse .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-header a.navbar-brand {
  color: #3e474f;
}
.main-content {
  margin-left: 175px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s linear;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
.nav-icons {
  padding-top: 12px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.nav-icons span {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px
}
.nav-icons a {
  color: #FF9900;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .sidebar-fixed {
    width: 85px;
  }
  .main-content {
    margin-left: 80px;
    padding: 0;
  }
  ul.sidebar-list {
    text-align: center;
  }
  ul.sidebar-list > li {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
  }
  .sidebar-fixed #ulGenres,
  .sidebar-fixed #ulPlaylists {
    margin-left: -40px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .sidebar-fixed li .nav-text,
  .sidebar-fixed li span.caret {
    display: none;
  }
}
/*Content*/

.pdsa-summary-block-primary {
  background-color: #428bca;
  color: #fff;
}
.pdsa-summary-block-primary .summary-footer {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}
.pdsa-summary-block-primary .summary-footer a {
  color: white;
}
.pdsa-summary-block-success {
  background-color: #3c763d;
  color: #fff;
}
.pdsa-summary-block-success .summary-footer {
  background-color: green;
}
.pdsa-summary-block-success .summary-footer a {
  color: white;
}
.pdsa-summary-block-info {
  background-color: #31708f;
  color: #fff;
}
.pdsa-summary-block-info .summary-footer {
  background-color: teal;
}
.pdsa-summary-block-info .summary-footer a {
  color: white;
}
.pdsa-summary-block-danger {
  background-color: #a94442;
  color: #fff;
}
.pdsa-summary-block-danger .summary-footer {
  background-color: red;
}
.pdsa-summary-block-danger .summary-footer a {
  color: white;
}
/*Structure of Summary blocks*/

.pdsa-summary-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0.3em;
  padding: 1em;
  min-height: 15em;
}
.pdsa-summary-block .summary-background i,
.pdsa-summary-block .summary-background div {
  margin-left: -0.4em;
  margin-top: 0.1em;
  font-size: 8em;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.pdsa-summary-block .summary-body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.3em;
  right: 0.8em;
}
.pdsa-summary-block .summary-body .summary-line-1 {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: xx-large;
}
.pdsa-summary-block .summary-body .summary-line-2 {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: medium;
}
.pdsa-summary-block .summary-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0em;
  right: 0em;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.4em;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: small;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.pdsa-summary-block .summary-footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.pdsa-summary-block .summary-footer:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Tunes</a>

      <div class="nav-icons">
        <a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
        </a>

      </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="sidebar-fixed" id="sideNavParent">
    <ul class="sidebar-list">
      <li>
        <a href="#"> <span class="nav-text"> Music</span>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-headphones"></span> 
        </a>

      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"> <span class="nav-text"> Home</span>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
        </a>

      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#nope" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ulGenres"> <span class="nav-text"> Genres </span>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>  <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>

        <ul id="ulGenres" class="collapse" data-parent="#sideNavParent">
          <li> <a href="#">All Genres</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#">Jazz</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#">Country</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#">Rock</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#nope" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ulPlaylists"> <span class="nav-text"> Playlists </span>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>  <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>

        <ul id="ulPlaylists" class="collapse" data-parent="#sideNavParent">
          <li> <a href="#">All Playlists</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#">My Top Rated</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#">Top Country</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#">Top Classic Rock</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"> <span class="nav-text"> Songs </span>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span> 
        </a>

      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"> <span class="nav-text"> Downloads </span>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span> 
        </a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="pdsa-summary-block pdsa-summary-block-primary">
            <div class="summary-background"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i>

            </div>
            <div class="summary-body">
              <div class="summary-line-1">14</div>
              <div class="summary-line-2">Genres</div>
            </div>
            <div class="summary-footer"> <a href="#">View Genres</a>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="float:right;"></i>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="pdsa-summary-block pdsa-summary-block-success">
            <div class="summary-background"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i>

            </div>
            <div class="summary-body">
              <div class="summary-line-1">5</div>
              <div class="summary-line-2">Playlists</div>
            </div>
            <div class="summary-footer"> <a href="#">See playlists...</a>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></i>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="pdsa-summary-block pdsa-summary-block-info">
            <div class="summary-background"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></i>

            </div>
            <div class="summary-body">
              <div class="summary-line-1">2143</div>
              <div class="summary-line-2">Songs</div>
            </div>
            <div class="summary-footer"> <a href="#">All Songs.</a>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></i>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="pdsa-summary-block pdsa-summary-block-danger">
            <div class="summary-background"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></i>

            </div>
            <div class="summary-body">
              <div class="summary-line-1">1</div>
              <div class="summary-line-2">Downloads</div>
            </div>
            <div class="summary-footer"> <a href="#">Get Downloads.</a>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right pull-right"></i>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="pdsa-readme-box pdsa-readme-box-primary">
            <br>
            <div class="readme-header"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></i>

            </div>
            <div class="readme-body">
              <h1>Free Music</h1>

              <p>Each day we have a free song selected especially for you!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="readme-footer"> <a href="#">+ See my song</a> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get that you have changed it to pixels but can I still use em? And what other changes have you made to the css and html? 
Kind regards,

Comment: Px or Em doesn't matter, that's just a choice. The biggest part to consider is how your sidebar vs the area your main content will sit, instead of trying to use columns (which are made to collapse across the viewport) use fixed width elements that you can adjust with media queries and then use columns inside those to hold your content, etc.